# Wordpress - How to do an excerpt of blog content without striptags

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, it can print a list of blog entries with excerpts.  When you click on a blog entry, it takes you to the full article.

My problem is that wordpress applies something like a "strip html tags" function to the excerpts, so that it removes ul,li, superscript, tags etc...

Is there a way to either prevent this, or be selective of which tags to strip out?  I definitely want to keep the superscript tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the excerpts contents, I suggest using [Advanced Excerpt Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/), or quite simply

```
the_content();
```